# Dual Booted Arch Linux | Windows 11 won't POST

Tags: arch-linux, gnu-screen, crash

recently, I started messing around with Arch Linux and was able to get it running dual-booted with Windows 11, running GRUB as the bootloader.

After doing this, I've been fine for pretty much a week with no issues only thing I've been doing was downloading packages for my setup. Today was really weird though.

first Qtile started not responding to my hotkey inputs, so then I decided to start fresh with a new config and reload. Once I did that everything was working fine and while watching a youtube video it just ended up glitching out. (The last second was repeating non-stop like a skipping CD and the whole interface froze. I couldn't move my mouse, quit out of qtile, or use any inputs to get back to the shell)...

After that horrifying experience, I went ahead and shut down the system manually by holding the power button.

the situation that I'm in now, is that my PC won't even POST. I've let it sit for a while (2 hours) thinking that might help but once I hit the power button again, it just hangs. Nothing comes up on the screen, just black. The monitor can't even pick up anything from my PC it just says, "no signal detected". What's even weirder is that I can't even manually turn off my PC, the power button is completely useless and the only thing I can do is shut it off from the back.

Does anyone have an idea of what's happening/happened? Did I fry my internals? Or am I still able to come back from this?

Any insight would greatly be appreciated. I kind of need my PC for other stuff too .

Comment: Your video card might have died. Remove it and try to power on.

Comment: Ended figuring it out after hours of being worried... turns out popping out the ram stick helped me get things up and running again. I don't know if this is a conventional way of fixing this issue but I now know what to do just in case. Thanks for taking the time! That def would've been my next thing to try. Thought my overpriced GPU would have to visit the dumpster  .

Answer (score 0):

I will post a proper answer. Whenever a machine does not boot there is roughly a troubleshooting task list:

1. Check power cables
2. Unplug all unnecessary USB stuff
3. Re-plug the stuff
4. Test GPU fitting
5. Check RAM fitting.
6. Test RAM sticks 1 per time